# Store and read password to/from keychain using Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

**EDIT: Issue has been resolved**. To contribute a bit to the community I setup some helper methods and an example how to use them on my blog. Find it here [KeyChain MT example](http://krumelur.me/2011/02/01/ios-store-passwords-in-the-keychain-using-monotouch-xamarin-ios/)

-- 
Original question:

Running iOS4.2 on Simulator and iPad.

I'm trying to store and read a password from the keychain using the code below. My inspiration for the code was https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone/ but I can't get it to work. What am I missing?

```
// Create a record.
SecRecord o = new SecRecord ( SecKind.GenericPassword );
o.Service = "myService";
o.Label = "myService";
o.Account = "test@test.com";
// The super secret password.
o.Generic = NSData.FromString ( "secret!", NSStringEncoding.UTF8 );
// Add to keychain.
SecKeyChain.Add ( o );

// Now cerate another recored to query what we just saved.  
o = new SecRecord ( SecKind.GenericPassword );
o.Service = "myService";
o.Account = "test@test.com";

// Query as record.         
SecStatusCode code;
var data = SecKeyChain.QueryAsRecord ( o, out code );

// This will tell us "all good!"... 
Console.WriteLine ( code );

// But data.Generic is NULL and this line will crash. :-(
Console.WriteLine ( NSString.FromData ( data.Generic, NSStringEncoding.UTF8 ) );
```

Comment: Good blog post, very useful, thanks!

Comment: Is this still the accepted method?

Comment: Your link in your post is broken

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than use `SecRecord`'s `.ValueData` try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(NSString.FromData(data.Generic, NSStringEncoding.ASCIIStringEncoding));
```

`Generic` returns NSData from where `SecKind.GenericPassword`'s are stored.

Comment: Does not work. I have changed the example above and still it does not work.

Comment: Works now! I figured out that adding the same record twice with different passwords does not overwrite/update the old one. Therefore it remained null. One has to use SecKeyChain.Update() to update existing records. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I added a link to my blog which contains a working example and some helper methods. Maybe it helps others.