# MonoTouch SecKeyChain.Add returning SecStatusCode.Param

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to save a record like so:

```
var testRecord = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
{
    CreationDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
    MatchCaseInsensitive = false,
    Service = "MyService",
    Label = "MyService",
    Account = "User",
    Generic = NSData.FromString("test", NSStringEncoding.UTF8),
};
SecKeyChain.Add(testRecord);
```

...but I'm getting SecStatusCode.Param back when I run it in the simulator.  According to the [documentation](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=T:MonoTouch.Security.SecStatusCode), that code means "Invalid or incomplete parameters passed" but I don't see anything missing or unusual that [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4852108/store-and-read-password-to-from-keychain-using-monotouch) aren't doing with apparent success.

Even adding CreationDate, Invisible, Description, Comment, Accessible, *and* ValueData properties to the SecRecord (some as in [this example](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/Keychain/Main.cs)) didn't help -- still getting SecStatusCode.Param.

Are there any non-obvious things that might cause a Param status code to be returned?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a lot of trouble trying to use the keychain. I finally got mine working to store user credentials in the app. Here is what I have:

```cs
        SecRecord existingRec = new SecRecord (SecKind.GenericPassword) { 
            Service = Keychain.USER_SERVICE, 
            Label = Keychain.USER_LABEL 
        };

        var record = new SecRecord (SecKind.GenericPassword) {
            Service = Keychain.USER_SERVICE, 
            Label = Keychain.USER_LABEL, 
            Account = username,
            ValueData = NSData.FromString (password),
            Accessible = SecAccessible.Always
        };

        SecStatusCode code = SecKeyChain.Add (record);
        if (code == SecStatusCode.DuplicateItem) {
            code = SecKeyChain.Remove (existingRec);
            if (code == SecStatusCode.Success)
                code = SecKeyChain.Add (record);
        }
```

Keychain is a static class with constants so I don't have to retype the strings.

The only thing different between yours and mine is the `CreationDate`/`MatchCaseInsensitive` properties and the encoding for NSData. Maybe try it without those and see if it works? If so, add them back separately and see what gives the problem.

Comment: The other difference was that I was using Generic -- as I'd seen in the sample I was going off of -- while you were using ValueData.  That ended up being the issue!

Comment: still having the problem

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you are running on the simulator - in that case you need to add an Entitlements plist in the project options for your current build config in order to make keychain access work.